# For what values of $k$ Calvin wins the game?

Tags: permutations, contest-math, combinations, game-theory

Let $k ≥ 1$ and $N > 1 $ be two integers. On a circle are placed $2N + 1$ coins all showing
heads. Calvin and Hobbes play the following game. Calvin starts and on his move
can turn any coin from heads to tails. Hobbes on his move can turn at most one coin
that is next to the coin that Calvin turned just now from tails to heads. Calvin wins
if at any moment there are $k$ coins showing tails after Hobbes has made his move.
Determine all values of $k$ for which Calvin wins the game.

> Here Calvin and Hobbes are names of two person.

**This is the problem from INMO 2023**

Can someone help me solving. I thought an approach but that was wrong gives a contradictory answer that's why I am not uploading here. Can someone help me figure this one?

Comment: So what is $\sf INMO$?

Comment: @youthdoo Indian National Mathematics Olympiad. Two steps prior to IMO in India.

Comment: Official solution can be found in https://olympiads.hbcse.tifr.res.in/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/INMO_2023-sols.pdf

Comment: @VTand So do we still need these posts on INMO problems?